# Is there any archaic word for "finally"?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, adverbs, archaicisms, literary-english

So I was wondering whether there is any archaic word that means "finally" or "at last"?

Comment: It really depends upon what you mean by archaic. Do you mean currently not used?  Of cryptic origin which seemingly has been lost to time?  Or just really, really old?  The word *ultimately* seems to date back to 1652 in English and is from the even older Latin roots.

Comment: You might be able to use "in the fullness of time" in some circumstances.  It's a phrase though so I won't offer it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"At length" is quite archaic, hardly ever used now. *At length they fell upon the opposing army*. They would also say "at the last" instead of "at last"...

Answer (score 1):

This is from Google's Thesaurus. 'Finally' is identified as having four meanings. Some of the synonyms proposed seem quite ancient to me - 'by and by', 'at length', etc.

finally
ˈfʌɪnəli/
adverb
adverb: finally
1.
after a long time, typically when there has been difficulty or delay.
"he finally arrived to join us"
synonyms:   eventually, ultimately, in the end, by and by, at length, after a long time, after some time; More
antonyms:   immediately

as the last in a series of related events or items.
"a referendum followed by local, legislative and, finally, presidential elections"
synonyms:   lastly, last, in conclusion, to conclude, in closing, to end, last but not least More
antonyms:   firstly, initially

used to introduce a final point or reason.
"finally, it is common knowledge that travel broadens the horizons"
in such a way as to put an end to doubt and dispute.
"the need to dispel finally the belief that auditors were clients of the company"
synonyms:   conclusively, irrevocably, decisively, definitively, definitely, absolutely,

for ever, for good, for all time, once and for all, permanently More
antonyms:   temporarily

Answer (score 0):

[Fynaly - Late 14th Century.](http://m.dictionary.com/etymology/finally?linkid=8uxrdf&srcpage=definition&site=dictwap). The meaning is the same, but the spelling is archaic.